# Доработка программы для поиска и замены слов. Python

Tags: python

При запуске программы происходит ошибка: TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (9 given). Туплю, не понимаю как исправить. Вот сам код:

```
import pyperclip
import re
while 1==1:
    begining = input('copy the text')
    text = pyperclip.paste() #Программа берет текст из буфера обмена
    print(text)
    words = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N'] #Те слова, которые ищет программа
    variants = ['A2','B2','C2','D2','E2','F2','G2','H2','I2','J2','K2','L2','M2','N2'] #Слова для замены
    trantab = {w:v for w,v in zip(words,variants)}
    def searcher(text):
        result = []
        for ch in text:
            repl = trantab.get(ch.upper())
            if repl and repl not in result:
                result.append(repl)
                yield repl
    print(*searcher(text),sep=', ')
    endresult = str(*searcher(text),sep=', ')
    pyperclip.copy(endresult) #Возврат результата в буфер обмена
    exit = input('Press + if you want to exit')
    if exit == str('+'):
        break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка из-за этой строки:

```
endresult = str(*searcher(text),sep=', ')
```

Функция `str` не позволяет передать итерируемый объект и разделитель, чтобы склеить их в одну строку. Используйте для этого метод `join`

```
endresult = ', '.join(searcher(text))
```